# get sharepoint list data into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My boss asked me today if it is possible to use Sharepoint list data into an external HTML website...

The client have a sharepoint intranet and an HTML website.

They are publishing news on their sharepoint but they'd like to recover the news (sharepoint list) and put them into the home page of the other website.

I saw some different possibilities using Jquery or JavaScript or else Json.
To the effect that i'm not a regular with these languages...
First question: Is that possible? Because i think the two websites have differents servers.
Second one: if yes, how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. A better place for your question might be over at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Anyways, you can of course use a variety of methods to get sharepoint's list data - for example using the REST interface:

```
function getListItem(url, listname, id, complete, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + id + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's some more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx

Comment: hello,
thanks for the answer.
The id after items...is it the item id or list id?

Comment: item id, as you see it was used later in the code in items(" + id + ")". You do not have to use my code as-is; You can modify the URL to your liking and to get best results - please read the link that I supplied as everything is explained there. Also if this answers your quesion please mark the question as "Answered". In case you have something else to ask please do not hesitate.

Comment: in fact i have several items to recover...
in fact i have to create a newsletter in html by using news who are in a sharepoint list

Comment: Attention, JavaScript is not crossdomain, so you won't be able to use it from two different websites (due to the same-origin policy): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

So at some point you'll have to use code from the server (like PHP, .Net, ...)

Comment: Yes AymKdn that's what i was afraid of

Comment: Did any of you read the link I supplied? The cross-domain problem is clearly laid out and explained there, in a very cryptic sounding "Using the Cross-Domain JavaScript Library" title.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is very much possible. You can consume webservices in sharepoint to expose data.

If you other server is purely HTML then the only way would be to go with consuming web services via Jquery.

However, if its PHP/Ruby or some other server, you can consume the services in the server side language as well.

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/got-rest-querying-sharepoint-list-data-using-rest-services-client-side-part-1.aspx